# Rhel 6 +nginx+apache+ redmine 2.6 => 403 error

Tags: apache, nginx, redmine, configuration, rhel

Проблема в конфигурировании nginx или прав доступа. Точно сказать затрудняюсь, затем и пишу.

Суть: есть **rhel6** , установлен и пашет nginx и apache. По адресу example.com доступен один php проект, по адресу *example.com: 3000* доступен редмайн.

Выделили поддомен который бьётся на тот же *ip* что и *example.com* . необходимо поддомен r*edmine.example.com* резолвить на апач по порту 3000. Сейчас если обращаться на r*edmine.example.com* то выдаёт `403` ошибку, а если по *redmine.example.com:3000* то открывает как и на *example.com:3000*, но эт потому что долбится на конфигурации апача мимо нджинкса. Apache слушает и 80 и 3000 порт.

В логе **nginx** пишет `directory index of /var/www/redmine/public/ is forbidden.....a`

Как правильно написать конфигурации **nginx`y** чтобы он правильно делал прострел на 3000 порт???

Comment: 1. selinux, [например](http://nix-tips.ru/nginx-i-selinux-pri-obnovlenii-do-rhel-6-6-centos-6-6.html). 2. возможно, у вас не согласовано, от имени какого пользователя работает *nginx*, и от имени какого пользователя *apache* обслуживает этот *virtualhost*.

Comment: У nginx пользователь nginx, у apache - apache. Права на папку с redmine принадлежат apache

Comment: а по первому предположению всё в порядке? тогда убедитесь, что пользователь nginx может просматривать содержимое **всех** каталогов по пути `/var/www/redmine/public/`: `sudo -u nginx ls /var; sudo -u nginx ls /var/www` и т.д.

Comment: только не совершайте, пожалуйста, классическую ошибку типа `sudo chmod -R ugo=rwx /какой/нибудь/каталог`

Comment: По запросам вплоть до public показывает все файлы. По первому пункту - я не знаю как использовать данную информацию, сижу читаю ( не разбираюсь я в проксировании через порты

Comment: первое предположение было не про проксирование через порты, а про selinux и его контексты. «вплоть до public» — public включительно?

Comment: Да включительно

Comment: хм. ну, *sudo*, теоретически, может и игнорировать selinux-овские контексты. для чистоты проверки я бы предложил [отключить selinux](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ru-RU/Fedora/13/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux.html) на время проверочного запроса. а вообще смотрите лог selinux-а (скорее всего, `/var/log/audit/audit.log`) на предмет сообщений по поводу nginx-а.

Comment: SELinux : status disabled

Comment: В логе указанном выше ток сообщения о хрон процессах, актуально ного или интересного нету

Comment: если disabled, то не актуально. тогда добавьте в вопрос содержимое задействованных секций *virtualhost* *apache*-а и задействованных секций *server* *nginx*-а.

Comment: Настроил конфигурацию nginx для домена как proxy , убрав вообще остальные настройки. Оставил только location / и proxy_pass, proxy_set_header....ну listen и server name оставил... В общем проблема решена))

Comment: Altenrion, опишите, пожалуйста, решение вашей проблемы в виде ответа к вопросу. это может помочь другим людям, которые столкнутся с аналогичной проблемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполняя просьбу   alexander barakin, размещаю ответ на свой же вопрос. 
Основная проблема как я выяснил оказалась связана с тем, что в одном из nginx конфиге для поддомена redmine я указал путь к дирктории redmine, в то время как необходимо было сформировать лишь проксирующий узел для скидывания запроса на виртуальный хост апача, с изменением порта обращения. Иными словами, запрос приходит на NGinx по 80 порту и поддомену, он разруливает по имени поддомена какой конфиг тягать, перекидывает запрос на виртуальный хост апача по 3000 порту. Важно: апач должен слушать этот порт. У меня выбран 3000 не набум, а из-за ruby машины, ну или pаssenger'a (точно не помню, но 1 из 2).

Таким обпразом привожу конфиги , которых более чем достаточно для проксирования через NGinx:

Конфиг NGinx:

```
server {

    listen  80;
    server_name redmine.example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/redmine.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/redmine.error.log;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

И конфиг виртуального хоста на апаче:

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public

    ErrorLog logs/redmine_error_log

RailsEnv development
    RailsBaseURI /

    <Directory "/var/www/redmine/public/">
            Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Но нужно понимать, что у меня по 3000 порту обращение идет только к Redmine. В ином случае конфиг апача нужно писать чутка иначе, т.е. имя вирт хоста более точно, а не *:3000 - что значит все обращения по порту 3000.

Проблема моя возникла из-за прав на чтение конфигов, ну и конечно не правильно настроенные конфиги nginx. Последнему необходимо лишь отпроксировать запрос.

Вот собственно и все) Кому поможет ставте лайки или просто оповестите меня, будет приятно))